# Add foreign address to IP tables to Docker Image

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

I am new to Docker. I have a sample website running in a Docker Container and I am trying to access it from another computer on the network.

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14184/docker-proxy
```

I tried to add `sudo  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` but the iptables don't seem to update. I have forwarded port 3000 on my router to the rasperry pi's IP, and I use that to ssh in, so I know that works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Docker is only listening for connections from localhost - to expose the port externally, the app will need to bind to `0.0.0.0:3000`. That is usually set in your webserver config rather than via iptables